# Roman numeral converter in Ruby

Tags: ruby, project-euler, converting, roman-numerals

For a Project Euler problem, I made a Ruby roman numeral converter:

```
def romanize(num)
    digits = {
        1000 => "M",
        900  => "CM", 500 => "D", 400 => "CD", 100 => "C",
        90   => "XC", 50  => "L", 40  => "XL", 10  => "X",
        9    => "IX", 5   => "V", 4   => "IV", 1   => "I"
    }
    digits.reduce("") do |acc, digit|
        key, numeral = digit
        occurances, num = num.divmod(key)
        acc + (numeral * occurances)
    end
end
```

This works great, but I'm not sure it's good Ruby. Specifically, I'm wondering if the body of the `reduce` block could be shortened, and if it could made more clear.

For example, I don't think its that obvious that `num` is being modified in the middle of the `reduce` block.

Also, I know I can monkey patch this into the `Fixnum` class, but that's not what I'm looking for.

**Update #1**

@Tokland's answer taught me some new things. His answer works well, and is pretty clever.

If I take just two of his concepts and apply them to mine, the `digits.reduce("") ...` block can be simplified to:

```
digits.map do |key, numeral|
    occurances, num = num.divmod(key)
    numeral * occurances
end.join
```

This needs one less line because it deconstructs the digit key/value in the block arguments. Also, it creates an array which is joined into a string at the end. For big numbers (around 100-trillion), this is much quicker.

The only problem I still see is that it's modifying the `num` variable, which is essentially global state to the block.

Comment: In this case: `|(key, numeral)|` -> `|key, numeral|`

Comment: @tokland Good catch. I've corrected it in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some notes:

- Use 2 spaces for indentation, not 4.
- `key, numeral = digit`: You can unpack block arguments: `do |acc, (key, numeral)|`.
- `Concat`ing strings is costly, better build an array and finally join it.
- You are using `inject`, which is great because it'a functional abstraction, but you are modifying `num` on each iteration, so it ends up being a weird mixture of functional and imperative style. I know it's a bit cumbersome, but conceptually it's better to keep also `num` in the accumulator.

I'd write:

```
digits.reduce(:output => [], :num => num) do |state, (key, numeral)|
  ocurrences, remainder = state[:num].divmod(key)
  {:output => state[:output] << (numeral * ocurrences), :num => remainder} 
end[:output].join
```

Comment: There's some good stuff I learned in this answer (such as unpacking arguments. Constructing an array with `reduce`/`inject` feels wrong, though, doesn't it? Even though that's what I did in mine, it seems like there should be a good `map` solution.

Comment: Also, I benchmarked constructing an array and then joining it versus string concatenation. For trivial examples, there's almost no difference. For a number in the 100-trillions, though, joining was much quicker (0.4s vs 2.5s).

Comment: Finally, while it is cumbersome, it's also very clever to use the accumulator to pass state from one iteration to the next. Avoids modifying anything external to the block. Maybe it's just me, though, but it seems like it's not obvious what's going on here at first glance. I'd be worried about doing something like this on a real project, because someone else might struggle to figure it out... and I might struggle to figure it out 6 months from now.

Comment: @ahuth: Indeed for a programmer not familiary with functional style this may be hard to grasp at first.  I don't think you can do it with `map` because there is state in the computation. In functional languages you'd probably write it with a recursive function (but it would be completely equivalent, a fold is a recursive abstraction). Instead of `state` you'd have the two arguments (`output`/`num`). I've used a hash instead of an array pair to try to make it more clear.

Comment: `digits.reduce([[], num]) do |(output, current), (key, numeral)|` ? Looks better than hash.

Comment: @VictorMoroz: yes, that's more compact. I usually use an array not a hash, in fact.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than looping through `digits`, you could break down `num` in a loop, like this:

```
@digits = {
  1000 => "M",
   900 => "CM", 500 => "D", 400 => "CD",  100 => "C",
    90 => "XC",  50 => "L",  40 => "XL",   10 => "X",
     9 => "IX",   5 => "V",   4 => "IV",    1 => "I"
}

def romanize(num)
  @digits.keys.each_with_object('') do |key, str|
    nbr, num = num.divmod(key)
    str << @digits[key]*nbr
  end
end

romanize(888) # => "DCCCLXXXVIII" 
romanize(999) # => "CMXCIX"
```

Note that

```
str << @digits[key]*nbr
```

leaves `str` unchanged if `nbr = 0`.

You could also do this using recursion:

```
 def romanize(num, str='')
  return str if num == 0
  key = @digits.keys.find { |k| k <= num }
  str << @digits[key]
  romanize(num-key, str)
end

romanize(888) # => "DCCCLXXXVIII" 
romanize(999) # => "CMXCIX"
```

Note both of these methods require Ruby 1.9+.  Since 1.9, hash pairs have been kept in the order in which they were added.  For Ruby 1.8x you would need to replace `@digits` with an array of key-value pairs or order its keys in an array `keys` and for each key `key` in `keys`, extract its value with `@digits[key]`.

Comment: Thanks for the recursive solution. If I'm not mistaken, this is tail-call optimized, too?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help you with that. In fact, this is the first time I've heard that term.  I looked it up and get the general idea, but best for someone else to answer that.